# Sort on last_updated no longer works

Tags: solr

Just upgrading from Solr 4.9 to 6.2.

Previously, "sort=last_modified desc" worked just fine (usually extracted from documents by Tika), but in 6.2 last_modified is apparently multivalued (why?) so Solr will not sort on it.

This seems like it should be such a simple thing but I've driven myself to the point of madness trying to find some documentation that will tell me:

(1) Why last_modified is multivalued?

(2) Is there a single-valued equivalent parameter I can use to sort by document date?

Comment: Yes - that seems to be the problem. I've been trying to debug this "at arms length" because I have no visibility into the schema. The Sys. Admin. just sent me a copy and I see that it is the managed schema with last_modified having a type of tdates rather than tdate. I still wonder at the logic of making a field like last_modified multivalued - don't see the use case at all.

Answer (score 0):

Which schema is that in? Usually, it is what you would define it to be. Unless you did not define it at all and used *schemaless* mode, in which any field added would be multivalued.

If you did use schemaless mode, just go back to a new collection and explicitly define the last_modified as you wish first, before doing indexing.